# In an asynchronous function in React Native, what can be done to prevent loss of performance when there are repeated clicks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, async-await

- Let's say that the button is clicked one after another.
- In this case, I do not want the functionC() to run at every click.
- However, every click functionA() and functionB() must work.
- I want the function C() to work according to the dataA and dataB values ​​in the last click.
- For example, if the button is clicked 100 times and the button is not clicked again within 5 seconds after the last click, the functionC() should work according to the latest dataA and dataB values.

```
async function functionABC() {

  try {
    var dataA = await functionA();
  } catch (error) { console.log(error); }

  try {
    var dataB = await functionB();
  } catch (error) { console.log(error); }

  try {
    await functionC(dataA, dataB);
  } catch (error) { console.log(error); }

}

<Button title="Buton" onPress={() => functionABC()}/>
```

NEW DESCRIPTION

(1)

- The button was clicked.
- functionA and functionB worked.
- It was clicked again before the 5 second period expired.
- functionC not worked.

(2)

- functionA and functionB worked.
- It was clicked again before the 5 second period expired.
- functionC not worked.

...

(n-1)

- functionA and functionB worked.
- It was clicked again before the 5 second period expired.
- functionC not worked.

(n)

- functionA and functionB worked.
- 5 seconds have expired.
- functionC worked.

Comment: Could you specify what your question is exactly?

Comment: It's not very clear what your asking here.  Is it that you don't want functionC to run unless functionA and functionB complete before the button is pressed again?

Comment: @Keith In order to be performing. I want the function C () to run once when there is a click in a row.

Comment: @Yann In order to be performing. I want the function C () to run once when there is a click in a row.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to somehow store an identifier for "last running function call" so that you can make your check before `functionC`. Using a `Symbol` works well in this case, but any other unique ID would be fine (for example an incremental integer, or an empty object).

```js
let lastClick

async function functionABC() {
  const thisClick = Symbol()
  lastClick = thisClick

  try {
    var dataA = await functionA();
  } catch (error) { console.log(error); }

  try {
    var dataB = await functionB();
  } catch (error) { console.log(error); }

  try {
    if(lastClick === thisClick)
      await functionC(dataA, dataB);
  } catch (error) { console.log(error); }

}


function functionA() {
  console.log('run A')
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
}
function functionB() {
  console.log('run B')
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
}
function functionC() {
  console.log('run C')
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
}
```

```html
<button onclick="functionABC()"> click me </button>
```

---

If you really need to artificially extend the time it takes for `functionA` and `functionB` to resolve (and to give your user more time to click again before calling `functionC`), you could use `Promise.all` as the simplest solution.

Note that this solution will call functions A & B concurrently. Also, I didn't take care of the error handling. This is just to give you ideas.

```js
let lastClick
async function functionABC() {
  const thisClick = Symbol()
  lastClick = thisClick

  const [dataA, dataB] = await Promise.all([
    functionA(),
    functionB(),
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))
  ])
  
  if(thisClick === lastClick)
    functionC(dataA, dataB)
}

function functionA() {
  console.log('run A')
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
}
function functionB() {
  console.log('run B')
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
}
function functionC() {
  console.log('run C')
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
}
```

```html
<button onclick="functionABC()"> click me </button>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted. But when I want to update a Hook State in the function it doesn't work properly.  For Example:
```function functionA()
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() =>
    {
        setHookStateExample(data);
        resolve(true);
    }, 500)
  });
}```

Comment: How can I handle this problem?

Comment: This seems like a completely different question. My answer above didn't even involve react. You should make a separate post w/ more context so that people can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for but according to your example I assumed that this is what you might be looking for.

```
  let counter = 0;

  async function functionABC() {

    counter++;

    try {
      var dataA = await functionA();
    } catch (error) { console.log(error); }

    try {
      var dataB = await functionB();
    } catch (error) { console.log(error); }

    if(counter % 100 === 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if(counter % 100 === 0) {
                 try {
                    await functionC(dataA, dataB);
                 } catch (error) { console.log(error); }
            }
        }, 5000)
    }   
}

<Button title="Buton" onPress={() => functionABC()}/>
```

Please let me know if not and what exactly you wish to acheive.

**EDIT**

```
let timestamp = 0;
let firstClicked = false;

async function functionABC() {

    const currentTimestamp = Date.now();
    
    try {
      var dataA = await functionA();
    } catch (error) { console.log(error); }

    try {
      var dataB = await functionB();
    } catch (error) { console.log(error); }
    
    if(firstClicked) {
       if(currentTimestamp - timestamp >= 5000) {
           try {
               await functionC(dataA, dataB);
               } catch (error) { console.log(error); }
           }
       }
    } 
    firstclicked = true;

    timestamp = currentTimestamp;
}

<Button title="Buton" onPress={() => functionABC()}/>
```

Comment: 100 is just one example. We do not know how much the user will click. I added a new comment and explained it step by step. I would be glad if you help.

Comment: OK. I edited the answer accordingly. Hopefully this is what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. As soon as the button was clicked, the functionC worked at that moment.

Comment: Yeh, my bad. didn't take into consideration the first click. I fixed it. hopefully will work now

Comment: Now that I saw Sheraff answer I understand I didn't understand you well enough. You should follow his second code block as I think this is the answer you are looking for.